# DNN Blog Module not saving posts properly

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

The DNN Blog is not saving the posts anymore. I can see the latest post in the Manage Content/Data, and it says it is visible but once you are out of the edit mode it is not there. Now, when I click on the save the alert comes up that says ***Had an error talking to the server (400)), Bad request, Could not find stored procedure ‘toSIC_EAV_ChangeLogAdd’. 
What I did I updated 2sxc App and the Content module to 9.32.0, and had no luck.
Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?
DNN Version v. 09.01.01 (129)

Comment: This is solved. I posted to the Module creator's 2sxc Git Hub. They gave me an SQL statement to run to add the Store Procedure which solved our problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran this stored procedure, which we got from the module creator's git hub, to fix our problem:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON       
GO      

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON        
GO      


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_ChangeLogAdd]     
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
@User nvarchar(255) = null  
AS      
BEGIN       
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from   
-- interfering with SELECT statements.  
--SET NOCOUNT ON;   

-- Insert statements for procedure here 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_ChangeLog] ([Timestamp] ,[User])   
VALUES (GetDate(), @user)   

DECLARE @ChangeID int   
SET @ChangeID = scope_identity()    
EXEC ToSIC_EAV_ChangeLogSet @ChangeID   

SELECT *    
FROM [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_ChangeLog]    
WHERE [ChangeID] = @ChangeID    
END     

GO
```